# How to display the full page back ground image?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an HTML design for a sign-in page. It's working quite well and good but the only problem is: I'm unable to display the background image on mobile screens. On large desktop screens the whole background image is visible but on smaller screens the background image is showing only half.

Please help me what I should edit to make the background image always fit the screen no matter how small or large it is?

**signin.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin:0;
        }

        .background{
            height: 100%; 
            background-image: url("7.jpg");
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            background-size:cover;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid background">

        <br><br>
        <h2 class="text-center" style="color:orange">Register</h2>

        <div>
            <form class="form-horizontal">

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email" style="color:orange">Name:</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Name" name="email" style="width:80%">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" style="color:orange">Username:</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter Username" name="pwd" style="width:80%">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" style="color:orange">E-mail:</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter E-mail" name="pwd" style="width:80%">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" style="color:orange">Password:</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" style="width:80%">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" style="color:orange">Confirm Password:</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="pwd" style="width:80%">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">

                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd" style="color:orange">Upload image:</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="file"  id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd" style="width:80%">
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">        
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Sign up</button>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pz7yxz53/)

Comment: Can you give a link to you background image(7.jpg)?

Comment: how to give the link ?

Comment: You can upload you image to Google Drive or Dropbox.

Comment: https://ibb.co/ghYQt8

Comment: see the above link sir i have uploaded my image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't ever mess with the containers when using Bootstrap (e.g., putting a `background-image` on the `.container` class. I would create a whole new `div` above or beneath it. Also, you need to make sure your `<div class="background">` covers all of your form content. If it doesn't, then that's when funky things might happen with the image.

This fixed the problem for me:

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**(Optional):** I noticed that the `.form-horizontal .form-group` Bootstrap CSS was making the forms push outside of the image. I fixed that by adding this style:

```
.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.background {
    background: url(image url) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This should be helpful, please check: [Full Page Background Image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: no sir it did not helped please can u see my code once again please please

Comment: please sir help me im really in need

Comment: Hey, Sure. For me, your background is working. So do you need it to be fit to the screen when its go to mobile?

Comment: yes sir absolutely i need that only what u said please help me please

Comment: when it goes to mobile site na then the back ground is showing only half but the back ground should be full when it goes to mobile site

Comment: I understand your issue. But to do that you need to repeat or have a very large image for your background. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/b3czdLhk/

Comment: i'm not getting sir please help me

Comment: Where is your background image?? Can you upload it

Comment: i have uploaded my image

Comment: see  the above link sir

Comment: Your image size is not enough to work on mobile like how you want. You will need to do a trick like; have the background image align to bottom and background colour to match the colour of the image top area. You may need something else, but there is no other way to do that nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Use viewport height and viewport width as so:

```
background-size: 100vh 100vw;
```

Refer:
http://www.tipue.com/blog/css3-vw-vh/

Or try:

```
.background{
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat
}
```

Refer:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the full image in that container , Use

```
.background {
   background-size:contain;
}
```

or you want to cover the container without showing the full image

```
.background {
   background-size:cover;
}
```

I use following code for background images

```
.background {
  height:98vh; /* view port height */
  width:100%;
  background:url(images.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Thanks You

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this

```
.background{
  height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  background-image: url("7.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

Set `background-size: 100% 100%;`

I forget about `background-attachment: fixed;`)